# numpy.loadtxt returns string repr of bytestring instead of string

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm having trouble reading a data file containing mixed strings and floats with numpy.loadtxt in Python 3. Python 2 works fine, but I want my code to work in Py3.

A simplified example:

```
import numpy as n

strings = ['str1', 'str2']
parsed = n.loadtxt(strings, dtype='str')
print('Result:', parsed)
```

which, when executed, gives different results for Py2 and Py3.

```
$> python2 mwe.py 
Result: ['str1' 'str2']
$> python3 mwe.py 
Result: ["b'str1'" "b'str2'"]
```

Python 2 gives strings as expected, Python 3 gives strings containing the string representation of bytestrings.

How can I get plain strings from this mess in Python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadtxt` has passed your input string through a `asbytes` function before parsing (it normally reads files as bytestrings).  But how it converts those to unicode does look buggy.

`genfromtxt` appears to handle this better

```
In [241]: np.genfromtxt([b'str1', b'str2'], dtype='str')
Out[241]: 
array(['str1', 'str2'], 
      dtype='<U4')
```

But it complains if you don't give it bytestrings:

```
In [242]: np.genfromtxt(['str1', 'str2'], dtype='str')
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Loading as `S4` and converting to unicode after is another option:

```
In [244]: np.genfromtxt([b'str1', b'str2'], dtype='S4').astype('str')
Out[244]: 
array(['str1', 'str2'], 
      dtype='<U4')
In [245]: np.loadtxt([b'str1', b'str2'], dtype='S4').astype('str')
Out[245]: 
array(['str1', 'str2'], 
      dtype='<U4')
In [246]: np.loadtxt(['str1', 'str2'], dtype='S4').astype('str')
Out[246]: 
array(['str1', 'str2'], 
      dtype='<U4')
```

Another work around is with a `converter`:

```
In [250]: np.loadtxt(['str1', 'str2'], dtype='str',converters={0:lambda x: x.decode()})
Out[250]: 
array(['str1', 'str2'], 
      dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll file a bug report against Numpy.